# What to do if dpkg is stuck while updating packages?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, dpkg, muon-package-manager

I just installed Kubuntu 11.10 and started to update packages. All packages downloaded and now it's stuck running dpkg, at 53%, for hours. What can I do now to not break anything? Should I reset my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for any reason, package installation fails (Update manager or Synaptic), you can attempt the following option.
Open a terminal, type "sudo dpkg --configure -a" and hit enter. 
Provide your root password.
After dpkg has finished, open synaptic, check for updates.
If something is wrong, synaptic will tell you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ran your command and then ran Moun Package Manager, and there were no indication of an error.

Comment: I reset my computer and did what Jean said, it seems that all packages were upgraded correctly because Moun Package Manager informs that no packages need upgrading. I hope there's no other problem because of this.